# Set Remote Computer To DHCP Enabled Without Using WinRM

Tags: powershell, dhcp, netsh

How can I set a remote computer to use DHCP instead of a static IP address?

I have tried using `Set-NetIPInterface -DHCP Enabled` however this requires WinRM which is disabled on my network.

How can I do it using a built in Windows technology like Netsh (I can't download PSExec).

Comment: Depending on the client version, you may have to use netsh anyway, the Net cmdlets require Windows 8 or newer, or Server 2012 or newer, as those cmdlets are part of the OS.

Comment: I'm using Server 2012. But it doesn't matter because WinRM is disabled.

Comment: Can you explain your whole scenario a little better? This sounds like a very in-the-weeds question, and you might get a more useful answer if you explain the entire problem that you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMI works well:

```
$networkAdapterConfig = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName 'SomeComputerName'
$networkAdapterConfig.EnableDhcp()
```